# Увеличение значения в базе по времени

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, как сделать чтобы через каждые 3 минуты в базе поле значения увеличивалась на 1?

У меня в игре есть бензин. Вот чтобы если бензин меньше 100, добавлять через каждые 3 мин +1, пока не будет 100.

Comment: @anonymous_911_ если не секрет, зачем вам это?  
Как варинт юзайте sleep и запрос на апдейт

Comment: Знаете что такое cron?

Comment: Нет, а что это?

Comment: @anonymous_911_, это [cron](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) ;)

Comment: Это можно решить просто средствами MySQL. Копайте в сторону `EVENT`.

Comment: А как cron запускать? Я не знаком с ним!

Comment: @anonymous_911_, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте скрипт каждые 3 минуты по cron и выполняйте запрос

```
UPDATE car SET gas = gas + 1 WHERE gas < 100
```